# Deleting old SVN Externals

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Running svn version 1.8

I have a directory with some svn externals in it defined using TortoiseSVN properties.
Also defined in this directory are some older externals - I have no idea where these are defined.

If I define a new external (for example, FreeRTOS pointing to tag 7.4) with the same name as an old external (for example, FreeRTOS pointing to tag 5.1), upon checking out, the old external will take priority.

If I type propset -R svn:externals, only the new externals are listed.

How are these old externals defined and how can I delete them?

Comment: Is this directory the root of Working Copy? Did you read about Inherited Properies in SVN 1.8? Can you show `svn pl -v` for dir (or pg svn:externals)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lazy Badger, your comment provided the inspiration required. The issue was the svn externals being defined in the parent folder.

I used `svn pl -v -R` in the root directory to list all properties recursively and found the externals from there.